# Kubernetes NetWork Policies. unable to 'wget' on to pod running on different namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

I have created two name-spaces named 'a' and 'b'

I have file structure like below..

**`on folder a`**

**nginx-deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-a
  labels:
    app-tier: UI
  namespace: a
spec:
  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app-tier: UI
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app-tier: UI
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**network-policy.yml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: np-a
  namespace: a
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: b
  
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: b
    
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
```

and applied both yml files using `kubectl apply -f`

**`on folder b`**

**nginx-deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-b
  labels:
    app-tier: UI
  namespace: b
spec:
  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app-tier: UI
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app-tier: UI
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**network-policy.yml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: np-b
  namespace: b
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: a
    
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: a
    
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
```

and applied both yml files using `kubectl apply -f`

**The problem**

So basically I want to allow traffic from namespace **a** to namespace **b** and vice-versa.

and i have exposed services using

```
$$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment-b -n b --port=80

$$ kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment-a -n a --port=80
```

And i have created busybox in namespace **a** using

```
kubectl run myshell --image=busybox -n a --command -- sh -c "sleep 3600"
```

And i have exec into busybox using

```
kubectl exec myshell -n a -it -- sh
```

Now Here is the output of **wget**

```
/ # wget nginx-deployment-b.b.svc.cluster.local
^Z[5]+  Stopped                    wget nginx-deployment-b.b.svc.cluster.local
/ # wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc.cluster.local
^Z[6]+  Stopped                    wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc.cluster.local
/ # wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc
^Z[7]+  Stopped                    wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc
/ # wget nginx-deployment-b.b.svc
^Z[8]+  Stopped                    wget nginx-deployment-b.b.svc
/ #
```

You can see that i'm neither able to connect to service running on namespace **a** nor **b**

What should i do to allow allow traffic from namespace **a** to namespace **b** and vice-versa?

Any suggestions or modifications.

Thanks

edit-1

Descriptions of networks policies ,
**`np-a`**

```
Name:         np-a
Namespace:    a
Created on:   2020-08-21 18:41:12 +0530 IST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 80/TCP
    From:
      NamespaceSelector: name=b
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: 53/TCP
    To Port: 53/UDP
    To:
      NamespaceSelector: name=b
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress
```

**`np-b`**

```
Name:         np-b
Namespace:    b
Created on:   2020-08-21 18:21:07 +0530 IST
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 80/TCP
    From:
      NamespaceSelector: name=a
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: 53/TCP
    To Port: 53/UDP
    To:
      NamespaceSelector: name=a
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress
```

Service descriptions

```
Name:              nginx-deployment-a
Namespace:         a
Labels:            app-tier=UI
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app-tier=UI
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.107.112.202
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.0.147:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

and

```
Name:              nginx-deployment-b
Namespace:         b
Labels:            app-tier=UI
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app-tier=UI
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.228.141
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.0.79:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cilium-operator-868c78f7b5-44nhn   0/1     Pending   0          7h58m
cilium-operator-868c78f7b5-jl5cq   1/1     Running   2          7h58m
cilium-qgzxs                       1/1     Running   2          7h58m
coredns-66bff467f8-lpck8           1/1     Running   2          8h
etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   1          7h8m
kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   1          7h8m
kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   3          8h
kube-proxy-f9vgr                   1/1     Running   2          8h
kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   2          8h
storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   5          8h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow egress on port `53` for DNS resolution

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: dns
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

You can have separate network policy like above in both the namespaces dedicated for DNS.

Also when you access a service which is in a different namespace you need to use `<servicename>.<namespacename>.svc` or `<servicename>.<namespacename>.svc.cluster.local`.

Hence the command to access `nginx-deployment-b` should be `nginx-deployment-b.b.svc` or `nginx-deployment-b.b.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: So before applying the policies you have described ..Is there need of any port expose on 53?

Comment: Nothing else is needed the just apply this polity on both the namespaces

Comment: I have added the policie's please check them once...and still i/m unable to 'wget'

Comment: ```/ # wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc.cluster.local



^Z[1]+  Stopped                    wget nginx-deployment-a.a.svc.cluster.local
```
After editing the network-policy IP addresses are not even showing

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe svc nginx-deployment-a -n a` and `kubectl describe svc nginx-deployment-b -n b`

Comment: I have added service as well as network policies description...and code as well as output...please verify and let me know where i'm missing....Thanks

Comment: This makes me think that it's not a network policy issue. Does it work without any network policy ?Can add output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220214/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-avsr).